# how to parse inner tag of xml in android

Tags: java, android

This is my xml. please tell me DOM parse method to parse the whole video tag. actually it has an inner tag of location that is disturbing me.

```
<video>
    <video_id>39</video_id>
    <title>test video</title>
    <description>asdasd asd as</description>
    <address/>
    <location>
        <longitude>-86.785012400000030</longitude>
        <latitude>33.353920000000000</latitude>
    </location>
    <phone>2055555555</phone>
    <website>http://www.google.com</website>
    <time>154</time>
    <youtube_url>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdfgd</youtube_url>
    <youtube_video_id>sdfgd</youtube_video_id>
    <category_name>User Content</category_name>
    <category_id>48</category_id>
</video>
```

Comment: Just a suggestiin but since this is for a mobile platform I think you should be using a less memory consuming parser, such as SAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial might help you
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Comment: its fine.. but i need the code for iner tag.like in this xml, location is the iner tag.please tell me how i ll parse this iner tag

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

  Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

NodeList itemDetail = element.getElementsByTagName("location");
  
  for(int j = 0; j < itemDetail.getLength(); j++) {

  element = (Element) itemDetail.item(j);
      name = element.getElementsByTagName("longitude");

}


}

Comment: sorry to disturb you again.. i want the whole tag of video in my program..how to parse it whole?also this location tag in it

Comment: Please at least summarize the tutorial here. If the link breaks, so does this answer. I didn't convert this to a comment because you've received some up votes, but please do consider expanding it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example reading your xml into a `Document` object and then using `xpath` to evalute the text content of the longitude node. Ensure that the `video.xml` is in the classpath of app (put it in same directory as the java).

I only add the xpath as a point of interest to show you how to query the `Document` returned.

```
public class ReadXML {

    private static final DocumentBuilderFactory DOCUMENT_BUILDER_FACTORY = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    private static final XPathFactory XPATH_FACTORY = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ReadXML().parseXml();
    }

    private void parseXml() throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder db = DOCUMENT_BUILDER_FACTORY.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("video.xml");
        final Document document = db.parse(stream);
        XPath xPathEvaluator = XPATH_FACTORY.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPathEvaluator.compile("video/location/longitude");
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(item.getTextContent());
        }
    }

}
```